# Como desabilitar o evento textchanged no evento load no Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, eventos, textbox, load

Tenho o seguinte problema:
tenho uma função que é chamada quando o button aciona o evento textchanged só que quando inicio o programa pela primeiro vez ele chama a função textchanged no evento load. Quero que ao iniciar o programa o textchanged não seja acionado embora o text da label.Código do form_load:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl_off.Text = "- Modo Offline, conecte para iniciar a contagem.";
     }
```

Código do evento text_changed:

```
  if (lb_TA.Text == "1")
            {
                turno_para_oee = "3";
                Tubeteira_Oee();
              }

  if (lb_TA.Text == "2")
            {
                turno_para_oee = "1";
                Tubeteira_Oee();
              }

  if (lb_TA.Text == "3")
            {
                turno_para_oee = "2";
                Tubeteira_Oee();
              }
```

}

Comment: será que não tem outra forma de declarar esse texto? na instância do "lbl_off"

Answer (score 1):

Tem duas formas de você resolver a princípio.

A primeira, e mais simples, é definir esse texto no TextBox na própria tela, na propriedade text do componente, não precisando fazer isso no evento de Load.

A segunda maneira é você remover a definição do evento do TextChanged do textBox, e só definir esse evento após ter alterado o texto, no evento Load:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl_off.Text = "- Modo Offline, conecte para iniciar a contagem.";

        lbl_off.TextChanged += _aqui_seu_evento_onChanged_;
    }
```

Comment: no caso a minha label que muda no textchanged não é essa lbl_off e sim a lb_ta sendo que nao defini nada para a label lb_ta no evento load

Comment: isso não resolve o meu problema

Comment: Mas o evento de changed é chamado ao alterar o o lbl_off.Text não é?

Comment: O evento de changed está sendo chamado no seu caso porque no Load da tela você altera o texto da label. Faça o que sugeri na primeira forma, na minha resposta, e remova do Form_Load. Vá nas propriedades da label e defina o Text que quiser por ali mesmo, não precisando ser no código.